# how to use plenty of `import`(s) on a separate file?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to use plenty of `import`(s) on a separate file?

I have more than 20 imports on one page.

I tried this way, But I think this only for `plugin`.

```
import '';
...

part 'pageA.dart';//error
```

**PageA**

```
part of selfTest;

class PageA extends StatefulWidget {
```

Comment: what's the problem in importing everything on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

A library or package usually have a dart file that exports/shows the classes and dart files you want to use in your project, for example lets say a package called MyMath has math functions with diferrent dart files:

```
MyMath:
- Trignonometric
- Algebra
- Calculus
etc...
```

A library usally shows a file with the name of the package my_math.dart which would look like this

```
  library my_math

  export 'src/trigonometric';
  export 'src/algebra';
  export 'src/calculus';
```

and then when you do `import 'package:mymath/my_math.dart';` in your project my_math imports (actually exports) all it inner files directly to your project

So for you to actually do that you would need to create a folder, put all your files you want to import there, and then create a dart file outside that folder that exports all of that so you only call it

```
  lib
  - selfTest (This is your folder)
    - testA.dart
    - testB.dart
    etc... all your 20 files
  - my_tests.dart // Where you will do all the exports
  - pageA.dart // your widget
```

now your `my_test.dart` will look like this

```
export 'selfTest/testA.dart';
export 'selfTest/testB.dart';
etc...
```

and in PageA you use `import my_test.dart` which handles all of your files